# Line-Laser --> data saving

Tags: c++, point-clouds

I have a line laser I am connecting to. I am new and going off examples to try to get it to work. Currently, the sensor has variable "aLine" (float) of 1x2048 of data in a while loop

To save reading time I am adding the snippets of code here. Starting with the beginning of opening the file to write to:

```
        ofstream myFile;
        myFile.open("My File.csv"); // Create file
```

Then the part that creates the array from point cloud:

```
// 8. calculate point cloud
                            cx::c3d::PointCloud pc(rangeImg.height(), rangeImg.width());
                            cx::c3d::calculatePointCloud(*calibs[aoi], rangeImg, pc);
                            for (unsigned y = 0; y < pc.points.height(); y++) //100
                            {
                                float height;
                                std::vector<float> aLine;
                                for (unsigned x = 0; x < pc.points.width(); x++) //2048
                                {
                                    height = pc.points.at<cx::Point3f>(y, x).z;
                                    aLine.push_back(height);
                                }
                            
                                
                                aLine.clear();
                                myFile << aLine;
```

I get the error <No operator matches "<<" these operands>

I am not sure how to proceed... please help.

Edit: Below is the code for more context:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/viz.hpp"

// C++ Wrapper
#include "cx_cam_common.h"
#include "cx_3d_common.h"
#include "AT/cx/CVUtils.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace AT;



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {   
        //Saving numerical values of aLine


        ofstream myFile;
        myFile.open("My File.csv"); // Create file

        // 1a. discover devices and choose the one to work with
        std::string uri = cx::discoverAndChooseDevice(true)->deviceURI;
        std::cout << "Open Device: " << uri.c_str() << endl;

        // 1b. connect camera
        auto cam = cx::DeviceFactory::openDevice(uri);

        // visualization frame
        cv::viz::Viz3d viz("Point Cloud");


        // Probe and set device settings:
        cx::Variant val;

        uint32_t numAOIs = 1;       // the number of AOIs, default is 1

        // a) Scan type of cameraT
        cam->getParam("DeviceScanType", val);
        if (std::string(val) != "Linescan3D")
        {
            cerr << "Current sensor devicemode is not 'Linescan3D', we activate it..." << endl;
            cam->setParam("DeviceScanType", "Linescan3D");
        }

        // b) Number of AOIs
        cam->getParam("NumAois", val);
        numAOIs = uint32_t(val);


        // c) Data Output Channels
        int numDC = 0;      // number of enabled data channels
        bool enableDC[3];

        // data channel 0 enabled flag
        cam->getParam("EnableDC0", val);
        enableDC[0] = (int)val >= 1;
        if (enableDC[0]) numDC++;

        // data channel 1 enabled flag
        cam->getParam("EnableDC1", val);
        enableDC[1] = (int)val >= 1;
        if (enableDC[1]) numDC++;

        // data channel 2 enabled flag
        cam->getParam("EnableDC2", val);
        enableDC[2] = (int)val >= 1;
        if (enableDC[2]) numDC++;

        // 2. load 3d-calibration from camera or file

        std::vector<cx::c3d::CalibPtr> calibs;
        double dy = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();

        for (unsigned int aoi = 0; aoi < numAOIs; aoi++)
        {
            calibs.push_back(cx::c3d::Calib::createShared());

            if (argc > 1)
            {
                // load the calibration from the given file
                calibs[aoi]->load(argv[1]);
            }
            else
            {   // load calibration from sensor, possible sources are "UserData", "Calibration", "CalibrationUser"
                cx::downloadCalib(cam->getHandle(), *calibs[aoi]);
            }

            // 3. set relevant acquisition parameters in calibration, we assume we have only one aoi active
            cx::updateCalibC5(cam->getHandle(), *calibs[aoi], aoi + 1);

            // set the profile-step-width scaling
            calibs[aoi]->getParam(CX_3D_PARAM_SY, val);

            if (aoi == 0)   // query profile distance only once
            {
                std::cout << "enter profile distance, current value=" << (double)val << ", new value: ";
                std::string userInput;
                cin >> userInput;
                if (!userInput.empty())
                {
                    dy = std::stod(userInput);
                }
            }

            if (!isnan(dy))
            {
                calibs[aoi]->setParam(CX_3D_PARAM_SY, dy);
            }

            // print updated calibration that is used to compute the point cloud
            cx::printInfo(calibs[aoi]->getHandle());

            char buffer[100];

            sprintf(buffer, "%s_%d", "CalibAOI", aoi);

            calibs[aoi]->save(std::string(buffer), "");

            // set the invalid value that will bes used in point cloud for all rangemap values that are zero 
            float ivd = NAN;    // could be any number e.g. -10.0f, if NAN is used the points are automatically suppressed in showPointCloud 
            calibs[aoi]->setParam(CX_3D_PARAM_METRIC_IDV, ivd);

            // Trigger cache update. When calling with argument > 0, the internal cache gets updated. 
            // This prevents a cache update at first call to metric functions cx_3d_range2calibratedABC.
            calibs[aoi]->setParam(CX_3D_PARAM_METRIC_CACHE_MODE, int(1));
        }

        // 4. Allocate and queue internal acquisition buffers
        cam->allocAndQueueBuffers();

        // 5. Start image acquisition
        cam->startAcquisition();

        while (1)
        { // 6. Grab acquisition buffer, wait for valid buffer with optional timeout. Timeout is given in ms.
            cx::DeviceBuffer buffer = cam->waitForBuffer(10000);

            // 7. get image data from buffer and do some processing on the image data (or get a copy for later use)
            // \note img holds a reference to the image data in the DeviceBuffer, if you need the image data after cx_queueBuffer you need to clone the image!
            {
                auto frameImg = buffer.getImage();
                frameImg->save("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\cxSupportPackage\\cx3dLib\\examples\\cpp\\vc140_64\\c5_snap_multipart_pointcloud\\x64\\Debug\\frameImg.tif");
                // optionally save range image to file
                if (argc > 2)
                    frameImg->save(argv[2]);


                // E.g. for two AOIS and DC1 and DC2 active, frameImg->data is aligned as follows: 
                //      (AOI1,DC1,profile#1) 
                //      (AOI1,DC2,profile#1)  
                //      (AOI2,DC1,profile#1) 
                //      (AOI2,DC2,profile#1)  
                //      ... 
                //      (AOI1,DC1,profile#n) 
                //      (AOI1,DC2,profile#n)  
                //      (AOI2,DC1,profile#n) 
                //      (AOI2,DC2,profile#n)
                // Reinterprete frameImg->data as if data channels were aligned side by side:
                //      (AOI1,DC1,profile#1),(AOI1,DC2,profile#1),(AOI2,DC1,profile#1),(AOI2,DC2,profile#1)
                //      ... 
                //      (AOI1,DC1,profile#n),(AOI1,DC2,profile#n),(AOI2,DC1,profile#n),(AOI2,DC2,profile#n)

                cv::Mat imgmat(frameImg->height() / (numDC * numAOIs), frameImg->width() * numDC * numAOIs, cx::cvUtils::pf2cv(frameImg->pixelFormat()), frameImg->data());

                std::vector<std::vector<cv::Mat>> images;
                images.resize(numAOIs);

                cx::Image rangeImg;
                cx::Image intensityImg;

                // split the multichannel/multiaoi image into separate images for each available data channel
                for (unsigned int aoi = 0; aoi < numAOIs; aoi++)
                {
                    images[aoi].resize(numDC);

                    int imgCh = 0;
                    for (int dc = 0; dc < 3; dc++)
                    {
                        if (enableDC[dc])
                        {
                            cv::Rect roi((int)frameImg->width() * numDC * aoi + (int)frameImg->width() * imgCh, 0, (int)frameImg->width(), (int)frameImg->height() / (numAOIs * numDC));
                            images[aoi][imgCh] = cv::Mat(imgmat, roi);          // get DC as submatrix from imgmat

                            if (dc == 2)
                            {
                                rangeImg = cx::cvUtils::imageCreate(images[aoi][imgCh]);
                                //rangeImg.save("rangetest.tif");

                                // 8. calculate point cloud
                                cx::c3d::PointCloud pc(rangeImg.height(), rangeImg.width());
                                cx::c3d::calculatePointCloud(*calibs[aoi], rangeImg, pc);
                                for (unsigned y = 0; y < pc.points.height(); y++) //100
                                {
                                    float height;
                                    std::vector<float> aLine;
                                    for (unsigned x = 0; x < pc.points.width(); x++) //2048
                                    {
                                        height = pc.points.at<cx::Point3f>(y, x).z;
                                        aLine.push_back(height);
                                    }
                                
                                    
                                    aLine.clear();

                                    // save the line here
                                    //myFile << aLine;


                                }
                                // 8b. Save data to PLY
                                std::string basePath = "../../../cx3dLib/data/";
                                std::string cloud_fname = basePath + "img/LaserData2.ply";
                                pc.save(cloud_fname, false);


                                // 9. show point cloud using OpenCV Viz3d module
                                cv::viz::Viz3d viz("Point Cloud.ply");
                                pc.computeNormals();                                            // compute normals from point cloud points
                                cx::normalizeMinMax8U(rangeImg, pc.colors);                     // compute colors from height values of range map. Function defined in cx_3d_common.
                                //pc.save("pc.ply");
                                cx::showPointCloud(viz, pc, "pc1", 2, cv::COLORMAP_JET + 1);    // 0=only show points without normals and static color, 1=use colors, 2=use colors and normals. Function from cx_3d_common.

                                                                                                // show range image in OpenCV window
                                cv::imshow("Range Image", cx::cvUtils::imageCopyToMat(pc.colors, false));
                                //pc.save("C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\cxSupportPackage\\cx3dLib\\examples\\cpp\\vc140_64\\c5_snap_multipart_pointcloud\\x64\\Debug\\pointCloud.ply"); //_%s",dc);
                                // 10. optionally save PointCloud to file
                                if (argc > 3)
                                    pc.save(argv[3]);

                                //std::cout << "CS: red=x, green=y, blue=z" << endl;
                                //std::cout << "3D-View: press 'q' for quit or 'h' for help" << endl;
                                //viz.spin();   // Wait for a keystroke in the OpenCV window
                            }
                            if (dc == 0)
                            {
                                intensityImg = cx::cvUtils::imageCreate(images[aoi][imgCh]);

                                //intensityImg.save("intensitytest.tif");
                                std::vector<unsigned short> aLine;
                                for (int i = 0; i < intensityImg.width(); i++)
                                    aLine.push_back(((unsigned short *)intensityImg.data())[i]);
                                aLine.clear();

                            }

                            imgCh++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // 11. Queue back the buffer to the devices acquisition engine.
            // \note From now on any references to the buffer images are not valid anymore and might be overwritten with new image data at any time!
            buffer.queueBuffer();

        }


        // 12. Stop acquisition
        cam->stopAcquisition();

        // 13. Cleanup
        cam->freeBuffers();
        cam->close();

        //std::cout << "CS: red=x, green=y, blue=z" << endl;
        //std::cout << "3D-View: press 'q' for quit or 'h' for help" << endl;
        //viz.spin();   // Wait for a keystroke in the OpenCV window
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "exception caught, msg:" << e.what();
        exit(-3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ostream out of the box doesn't handle vectors. You will have to add an overload for the operator<< : `ostream::os& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<float>& values)` and then write out the data in a format you would like.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```cpp
myFile << aLine;
```

has `aLine` as an operand, which is of type `std::vector<float>`. C++ does not know how to write a `std::vector<float>` to a file, resulting in your error.

To write to file, one possible solution is to iterate across your vector

```cpp
for (float element : aLine) {
    myFile << element;
}
```

Comment: There should be at least some delimiter outputted between those elements inside the loop.

Comment: I edited my original post to give some context of the process. One of the concerns I have about this would be that a for loop might not be efficient (if I am understanding correctly your approach). The overall while loop is taking images and converting them to point clouds (which is already a heavy load to do for the hardware).
Would there be a way to open a file, append the vector to the file for each iteration of the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a overloaded function (template) that can output for collection types. Here is a generic (C++20) solution (ofcourse you could also make one that accepts only a `const std::vector<float>&`.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>
#include <list>
#include <string>

// operator<< has already has overloads for string like types
// but string like types are also containers.
// so we need only to overload for containers that are not string like
// or the compiler starts to run into ambiguous overloads.
// 

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// so setup some compile time checks
// to distinguish between containers and string like types
//

template<typename type_t>
constexpr bool is_non_string_like_container()
{
    return 
        std::ranges::common_range<type_t> && 
        !std::is_convertible_v<type_t, std::string_view>;
}

template<typename type_t>
concept IsNonStringLikeContainer = is_non_string_like_container<type_t>();

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// a function template (using C++ auto + concept restrictions)
//

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const IsNonStringLikeContainer auto & values)
{
    bool comma{ false };
    
    os << "[";
    for (const auto& value : values)
    {
        if (comma)
        {
            os << ", ";
        }
        os << value;
        comma = true;
    }
    os << "]";

    return os;
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// and test output on a few containers

int main()
{
    std::array arr{ 1,2,3 };
    std::vector<int> vec{ 4,5,6 };
    std::list<std::string> list{ "the", "quick", "brown", "fox" };

    std::cout << arr << "\n";
    std::cout << vec << "\n";
    std::cout << list << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```